# CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers with zero ports on Linux

Tags: java, linux, rxtx

i am trying to connect serial port on ubuntu. However, It doesn't work for me. I succesfully run the same project on Windows just with different drivers. The problem is that I can't load any ports while I am using this:

CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers(); // i am using rxtx 2.1.7

It always return zero ports. I would like to use port ttyS0 whichworks great with minicon so i am sure that port is not blocked and the machine is not broken.

Anyone has a reason for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was just becouse low priviligies. I had to add myself to a group which is supposed to work with ttyS0.

Answer (score 3):

I used this command

sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0

I had the same problem and it worked the moment after I used this command. Like Smolda said, it is a permission problem.

Answer (score 3):

if nothing helps, you should consider to add this line to your java code:

```
System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/yourtty");
```

did it for me. (Only if you work with the RXTX library)

Comment: After first checking the accepted answer, It didn't work for me. After another hour of investigation, it seems this is a bug in RXTX2.2 which requires to set this gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts property - see also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rxtx/+bug/367833